# Find where the quadratic $x^2-2x-3 =0$ and use this to show that the sequence ($x_n$) is strictly increasing.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

I have solved part (i) by rearranging $L = \sqrt{(2L+3)}$ to get $L^2-2L-3=0$, and then solving this quadratic to get $L = 3$ or $L = -1$. And since $3\gt -1$, the upper bound must be $3$.

For part (ii) I have established that $x$ is negative for $-1 \lt x \lt 3$. I think that this implies that the difference between $x_n$ and $3$ is getting smaller and smaller as $x$ approaches $3$ from the left. And since $x_1=1$ this would suggest that $x_n$ is strictly increasing.

However I'm not sure how to prove this properly.

Comment: The bound can be proved by induction. So can the fact the sequence is increasing,

Comment: For ii) you can use that $x_{n+1}-x_n = \sqrt{2x_n + 3} - x_n$ together with $x_n^2 - 2x_n - 3 < 0 \implies \sqrt{2x_n + 3} >  |x_n|$ so $x_{n+1} - x_n > 0$ if $x_n\in(-1,3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a):$ by induction on $n$: $x_1 =1< 3, x_n < 3 \to x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2x_n+3} < \sqrt{2\cdot 3+3} = 3$, thus this shows that $x_n < 3, \forall n \geq 1$.

$b)$: $x_{n+1} > x_n \iff \sqrt{2x_n+3} > x_n \iff x_n^2 -2x_n - 3 < 0\iff (x_n+1)(x_n-3)<0 \iff -1<x_n <3$ which is true from part $a)$ and the fact that $x_n > 0$.